# Bootstrap Navigation bar won't show

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I wanted to add nav-bar to my page using bootstrap but it just won't show up for some reason, I've properly downloaded bootstrap files and jquery 3.5.1 and everything but my navbar still won't show up, I'm not sure if this will help but when I inspect the page(console gives no errors btw), it shows that the styles from bootstrap are being overridden

[Bootstrap styles are not being applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6wmA.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
  <meta charset ="utf-8">
  <meta name= "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale =1">
  <title>Solution Assignment Module-3!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>

 <header>
  <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">

    </div>
  </nav>
 </header>





<script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you expecting to show when you have not input any of the other navigational components (ex. logo, menu items, collapse toggle, etc) into your navbar.

Comment: I was watching a similar thing being done and it should give an effect like this https://imgur.com/FNCuDLi.jpg

Comment: So Bootstrap 4 doesn't support `navbar-default` you would need to use `navbar-light bg-light` or `navbar-dark bg-dark` or some other variation. At MOST without any additional content that gets you a small ribbon of color because the height of the navbar component is determined by its padding and the content within it.

Comment: hmm okay I got this figured out thanks to you, I have got another problem (if you don't mind) I'm basically using the col-md-4 for 3 sections, each section should basically take equal amount of width of the browser meaning the 3 sections should be equal in width, adding margins to be able to give them some space causes the 3rd section to go into the next line, I can't seem to figure this out

Comment: Bootstrap's Grid already has margins built in. If you are applying a background color to whatever content is in each column you should do so in a wrapper div (ex: `<div class="col-md-4"><div class="my-bg">Lorem Epsom...</div></div>` and not to the column itself.

Comment: hmmm i've done this but it still gives the same problem

`<section>
 <div id="SecondSection" class= "col-md-4  col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><h3 class="SectionHeader text-center">Beef</h3>
 <br><br>
lorem epsom....
<div><a href="#Page-Header">Back To top</a></div></div>
</section>`

Comment: Make sure you're following Grid formatting correctly.  For that `<section>` to be valid it should be `<section class="row">...</section>` and that itself should be the child of a container wrapper.  Also note that `col-xs-*` no longer exists in Bootstrap 4, and you can take advantage of their margin helper utilities to avoid using `<br />` for additional spacing.

Comment: Having a row inside a container just makes everything even smaller, looks bit squashed, should my code be something like this?
https://jsfiddle.net/qx37md9k/1/

Comment: You need to really review Bootstrap's documentation; the way you're applying padding, margin and background coloring directly to the column wrapper is the problem.  Written according to best practices your code would look more like: https://www.codeply.com/p/8KDmbgB4AB

Comment: I see, I thought I only need to identify the columns once for the entire thing since it would act as some sort of container itself, but I'm a bit confused shouldn't it be identified after the row class just once? I mean you have a container and inside you have a row and inside that row you specify how it should be divided, and in that case just once right? why are we always specifying col-md-4 before each section (in this case 3 times) instead of one?

Comment: My understanding was that you wanted each `<section>` to be its own column. That's why there are 3 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got this error because you added latest version of bootstrap CSS file and "navbar-default" not supported on latest version.

You can use older version of bootstrap CSS like I did here or add latest nav bar code according to latest version of bootstrap.

You can try this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang = "en">
        <head>
          <meta charset ="utf-8">
          <meta name= "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale =1">
          <title>Solution Assignment Module-3!</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
        </head>
        <body>
    
         <header>
          <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">menu1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">menu2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">menu3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">menu4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">menu5</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
         </header>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        </body>
        </html>
```